# What is the name of this structure (describes relation: exp(log(a) + log(b)) = a * b)?

Tags: category-theory

I recall reading some time ago about some pattern/structure in category theory. Now I need to study some related properties and can't recall the proper name of it.

Let me describe it (pardon me if I am not 100% precise with my notation).

Let `A` be monoid over set `a`, with identity element `a_id` and binary assoc. operation:

```
(a op_a a) -> a
```

Likewise `B` is a monoid over set `b`, with identity element `b_id` and binary assoc. operation:

```
(b op_b b) -> a
```

What is the name of structure `S`, that consists of:

- `A`
- `B`
- mapping `m1`: `a -> b`
- mapping `m2`: `b -> a`

... such that:

```
(a1 op_a a2) = m2(m1(a1) op_b m2(a1))
```

... for all `a1`, `a2` in `a`?

Example of this in math is:

```
exp(log(a1) + log(a2)) = a1 * a2
```

... with `A` and `B` being monoids over rational numbers with multiplication and addition operations, `m1` being `log` and `m2` being `exp`.

Another `S`-like structure example is when you define mappings for `integers <-> strings` (where strings are limited to be repetition of some symbol n times) and `sum` and `concat` forming monoids.

So, what is the proper name for this structure in category theory (or other branches of math)?

Comment: It seems that you are trying to describe the situation where $A,B$ are monoids and $m_1: A \to B$ is an isomorphism or at least an injective monomorphism. However, the requirement you have set down does not *quite* imply that. Do you more generally want that $m_1(\mathrm{id}_A) = \mathrm{id}_B$ and $m_1(a_1 \circ_A a_2) = m_1(a_1) \circ_B m_1(a_2)$?

Comment: If $m_1$ and $m_2$ are not supposed to be homomorphisms a priori, then this situation reminds me to having a structure (now monoid) $A$, a *set* $b$ and mappings $m_1:a\to b,\ m_2:b\to a$ that are inverses to each others (=> bijections). Then it implies a sturcture $B$ of the same kind on $b$. -- Even if this is what you think of, I don't know if it has any specific name..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for [group isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_isomorphism). Kudos to commenters for pointing me in right direction.